# Passing viewstate/event validation token; special chars causing issues

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-4.0

I have a viewstate and eventvalidation token that I am trying to pass in with my app.

The issue I am running into is that I am passing this info in:

```
string.Format("__EVENTTARGET=&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__LASTFOCUS=&__VIEWSTATE={0}&__EVENTVALIDATION={1}&{2}", viewstate, eventvalidation, request)
```

eventvalidation has a plus sign in it (+) which is causing a cat of the string, instead of displaying the literal character. Any ideas how I can prevent this from happening?

Here is my code to do the request:

```
WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(url);
//Here Request is working properly; the EVENTVALIDATION token has the + sign in it.
byte[] send = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(request);
// I think after I convert it to byte[], it is doing something bad to the EVENTVALIDATION token.
req.Method = "POST";
req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
req.ContentLength = send.Length;

Stream sout = req.GetRequestStream();
sout.Write(send, 0, send.Length);
sout.Flush();
sout.Close();

WebResponse res = req.GetResponse();
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream());
string returnvalue = sr.ReadToEnd();

return returnvalue;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used Uri.EscapeDataString and this did the trick!

Answer (score 1):

Use `String.Concat()`

```
String.Concat("__EVENTTARGET=&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__LASTFOCUS=&__VIEWSTATE=", 
           viewstate,"&__EVENTVALIDATION=", eventvalidation,"&", request);
```

Comment: Still running into the same issue, the EVENTVALIDATION is:
blahblahblahblah+blahblahblahblah

and its coming over as 
blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblah

Answer (score 0):

Try using an `HTMLEncode` to take away the +. Are you placing this in a HiddenField?

```
String.Format("__EVENTTARGET=&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__LASTFOCUS=&__VIEWSTATE={0}&__EVENTVALIDATION={1}&{2}", Server.HtmlEncode(viewstate), Server.HtmlEncode(eventvalidation), Server.HtmlEncode(request)))
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3te6wfz.aspx

Comment: Doing an HTML encode did not resolve the issue either.

the EVENTVALIDATION should be:
/wEWCgLovI7yCgLWx/zfCALd4faqDQLLnOKMCQKU84j8BQL36/XRCwL36/HRCwLchKvhBQKEj7DKBgLBnObwCxuhlgMcSF3Z9F+V882ftSalMi3s


But it is coming through as:


/wEWCgLovI7yCgLWx/zfCALd4faqDQLLnOKMCQKU84j8BQL36/XRCwL36/HRCwLchKvhBQKEj7DKBgLBnObwCxuhlgMcSF3Z9F V882ftSalMi3s

(notice the space vs the plus sign), even with HTML Encoding.

Answer (score 0):

`HttpUtility.UrlEncode` will encode the values correctly for your specified content type. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3208555/does-httputility-urlencode-match-the-spec-for-x-www-form-urlencoded) for more specifics.